# How to have your auto-complete form styled in a way where the fields come to the front and above other fields below it?

Tags: php, forms, jquery-autocomplete

Basically I would like the autocomplete form styled in a way where it comes above and in front of the other fields below it.

I have four fields and a button.
1. Name
2. Email
3. University ( auto complete field)
4. Course
Submit

Whats happening, is that that when the user clicks university and types a letter. The auto complete works but the list of universities appears behind the course field and submit button.

I would show a picture but Stack over flow says I have to earn 10 points before so.

So I hope that makes sense.

Thanks.

Below is the html code for the specific field which has the auto complete (the university field):

```
<div class="wrapSearch">
<input name="university" type="text" class="required noUniversity" id="input1" value="University" onFocus="if (this.value == 'University') {this.value=''}" onBlur="if(this.value == '') {this.value='University'}" onkeyup="autoSuggest(this.id, 'listWrap1', 'searchList1', 'input1', event);" onkeydown="keyBoardNav(event, this.id);" maxlength="100" /> <div class="listWrap" id="listWrap1"> <ul class="searchList" id="searchList1"></ul></div></div>
```

If you need more information on specific code to help you solve this issue, let me know. Will be happy too!

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You need to look at some examples of the CSS Z-index property. You can use it to force elements to appear above or below other elements. Look here http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_pos_z-index.asp for a good description.